# how do i keep form data after submitting the form using javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms

When i submit this form, the values just disappears from the textboxes. I like them to stay printed in the textboxes. How do i do that?

```
<form id="myform" method="get" action="" onSubmit="hello();">

       <input id="hour" type="text" name="hour" style="width:30px; text-align:center;" /> :
       <input id="minute" type="text" name="minute" style="width:30px; text-align:center;" />
       <br/>
       <input type="submit" value="Validate!" />
    </form>

    <style type="text/css">
    .error {
        color: red;
        font: 10pt verdana;
        padding-left: 10px
    }
    </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hello(){

    var hour = $("#hour").html();
    alert(hour);
}
    $(function() {
        // validate contact form on keyup and submit
        $("#myform").validate({
            //set the rules for the fild names
            rules: {
                hour: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 1,
                    maxlength: 2,
                    range:[0,23]
                },
                minute: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 1,
                    maxlength: 2,
                    range:[0,60]
                },
            },
            //set messages to appear inline
            messages: {
                hour: "Please enter a valid hour",
                minute: "Please enter a valid minute"
            }
        });


    });
    </script>
```

Comment: where do you want to keep that data?what you want to do with that data?pleas eexplain your question in detail.

Comment: thanks for the comments, when i submit the above form, the values just disappears from the textboxes, i like them to stay printed in the textboxes, how do i do that?
many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you submit a form, the entire page is replaced with the response from the server. If you want to stay on the page (rather than having it replaced by the response), you might look at using [`jQuery.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send the form data to the server rather than actually submitting the form.

Comment: This sounds really interesting, i'll google a bit to see how to do the jquery.post and give you a feedback

Comment: @Lina: Be wary of several of the "submitting a form using jQuery" articles you see out there, you'll see a lot of things like this: `var q = "?fname=" + $('#firstNameField').val() + "&lname=" + $('#lastNameField').val()";` presented as though they were a good thing. You really, *really* need to encode those parameter values via `encodeURIComponent`, you can't just grab them as in that code. (Consider what would happen if you had a "company name" field and someone put in the value "Foo & Bar Limited" -- that `&` really needs encoding.) It's not complicated, but people miss it out. Enjoy!

Comment: that is a great advice that i will always appreciate :)

Answer (score 12):

As soon as you submit the page, the data is sent to the server and a new page is loaded. In your case, this is the same page as before but that doesn't make a difference for the browser. To keep the values, you must fill in the values *on the server* while rendering the page.

Usually, you can simply copy the data from the HTML request parameters into the fields.

Comment: Usually, you *cannot* simply copy the HTML request parameters into the fields. You must HTML-escape them first, or your page will be wide open to XSS attacks.

Comment: Huh? When you read the parameters, your HTML framework should have decoded them for you. When you write them out, your output writer should encode them properly. I don't see your point.

Answer (score 1):

In the form tag, include `onsubmit ="return false"` to avoid form reset.
For example:

```
<form name = "inputNumbers" onsubmit ="return false">
```

Comment: This doesn't work... Submit function is disabled in this way

Comment: it satisfy my case. thank you ,where i use form only for required validation and for request i use Ajax call

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies from JavaScript to keep values in. Basically you access something called `document.cookie`.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, to retain the data in a text input:

```
<input type="text" name="inputText" id="inputText" placeholder="Enter the name of your all-time favorite Duckbilled Platypus" value="@Request["inputText"]" autofocus style="display: inline-block;" />
```